# Excel 2010 Workbook file not opening

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, vsto

I have created one Excel 2010 Workbook project in Visual Studio 2013.
There are three sheets in this workbook project.

Output of this project is "File_Name.xlsx". 
It was working fine till Yesterday.Now when I hit run, somehow it just opens excel without any workbook in it.

I repaired my Office still issue persists.I also tried to open the "File_Name.xlsx" from debug folder still same issue.

Any idea what could have gone wrong? How can I trouble shoot it?

Comment: First open Excel and then attempt to open the file using Excel's menu system.

Comment: I tried it Gary, still empty excel without any workbook.

Comment: Are you able to open the solution (.sln) in Visual Studio and view the code attached to the workbook? And the sheets in the workbook?